# Leaflet: get the color of a specified pixel on the map

Tags: leaflet

I need to get the color of a specified pixel on the map. How can I do it using the current API of Leaflet?

Comment: Wow. I thought this was an interesting question, and to my surprise [it is entirely non-trivial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936021/javascript-eyedropper-tell-color-of-pixel-under-mouse-cursor)!